# Phoebe's favorite insect

Tags: pattern

> If Charity wants to be happy on Mondays,
>
> If Mark's thing falls into water,
>
> and if Velma eats fruits with her fingers,
>
> What would Phoebe's favorite insect be ?

Hint

> All non-function words in each of the first three lines relate to a common concept. The three concepts belong to a pattern, which will help you deduce the concept linked to the fourth line... and hopefully the favorite insect.

Hint 2

> Isn't Velma in some famous group ? Isn't Mark ?..

Comment: Argh, I can't find the answer. This is going to bug me... :) Nice puzzle! Have an upvote.

Comment: @Brandon_J that pun aaah

Answer (score 7):

I think it could be:

> Zoraptera

Because pattern could be:

> **C**harity -> **M**ondays
>  **M**ark -> **W**ater
>  **V**elma -> **F**ingers
>  First letter is always shifted by 10 for next word. *C=3, M=13, W=23, V=22, F=32-26=6*
>  So **P**hoebe -> insect that starts with **Z**…

Comment: nice try ! however, all non-functionnal words are important in this riddle, not just the first and last ones. I've edited a hint.